# ggplot2 plotting function with range of arguments

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the following function, using ggplot2.

```
change <- function(score, d, k, p) {k*(score - 1/(1+k^(d/p)))}
```

I would like to see the results as a function of argument d. What's wrong with the following code?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggp <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0:10)), aes(x)) + 
    stat_function(fun=change, args=list(1, x, 100, 400))
ggp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the arguments as a named list(without *x*) works:

```
ggp <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0:10)), aes(x)) + 
    stat_function(fun=change, args=list(score=1, k=100, p=400))
```

*From the help page*:

> args: list of additional arguments to pass to fun

Comment: Thank you. Do you also know how to directly reference variables in a giben data.frame. Like for example, if i would not want to plot as a function of my x variable but some other variable, (if data.frame(x=c(0:10), y=c(10:20)))

Comment: Specify the *mapping* `aes(x = y)` in `ggplot` should do it if you want to plot against `y` variable for instance.